# Provision for Learning's Section

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Firstly, I would like to thank your forum, it's member's and expert's for their wonderful contribution to skill the masses.

I would like to suggest your forum to add a Learning's section where after all the discussions and technical brainstorming one can just describe their final code and how the final code works that can be of great help to beginner's to gain more insight on something that is working.

Also the functionality of displaying questions which are answered but doesn't have a correct answer yet on a separate tab (similar to Unanswered) would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Yash